# How much/fast is a battery allowed to degrade?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

My friend's Macbook Air battery has degraded almost 21% in just over 2 years. This made me wonder how much a battery is "allowed" to degrade over time. Is 21% in 800 days a lot? Or does it seem like a normal amount? The battery has had 610 load cycles.

[image]

It's purely out of interest, because his computer claims he should get the battery serviced, but maybe 21% is very normal on such a timespan. It's a lithium-ion battery.

I have no idea if this is the right stack to ask it, but it seemed most fitting.

Comment: This is pretty normal. Almost everyday charging for two years will certainly have adverse effects.

Comment: My Lenovo has some battery management software that has "Battery Life Extension" setting ... it's keeping my battery at 62-64% of charge. This is fine for me as I tend to use it docked or I have access to power all the time. I have to change it if I plan to need the extra capacity. Me and planning only get on when it comes to work projects .... mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery is doing well.
Lithium Ion (LiIon) & Lithium Polymer (LiPo) batteries are essentially identical for practical purposes.
LiIon/ LiPo batteries have cycle lives typically in the 300-600 cycles range for relatively deep discharge use, and you can get substantially more cycles of lower discharge depth. As discharge depth decreases the maximum total energy stored and retrieved increases. eg a battery that gave 500 x 100% discharge cycles or 500 x initial capacity but the same battery **may** give 1200 x 50% discharge cycles or 600 x initial capacity.

As well as cycle life LiIon batteries have a "calendar life" - 'the clock starts ticking' as soon as they start to get used and a battery with minimal use will still have a finite lifetime.

In the example here there have been 610 cycles in about 700 days - we do not know how long from manufacture to start of use - so maybe only 600 days of use or approaching one cycle per day. This suggests that the user charges the battery every day regardless of state of charge at end of the day. It is also possible that your friend charges the battery at work (university, school ...) and at home   so gets 2 cycles per day. And they may have it on power most of the time so that the discharge depth is seldom very high.

I do not know how Apple measure "cycles" - they **might** determine % of charge to full and call that say 60% or 30% of a cycle **but** it is much more likely that they call every charge a cycle.

So - it is not possible to know from the information provided how much use the battery has really had, but the figure given is well within the range of normal".

Comment: Why the 'more soon'? Why not just complete your answer in one go?

Comment: @user36129 - Extensive bitter experience in several areas. This question WILL be deemed by some to be a non-design question, even though it helps people who design battery systems, and the knee-cap gang may come along at a moments notice and close the question - as happens more often than I'd like. If I have an answer under under preparation and the question is kneecapped it will not accept my answer and I have the choice of having wasted sometimes considerable effort or finding ways to post it anyway - eg create another question and answer it. ....

Comment: .... For very worthwhile questions and subjects I have done that BUT it takes substantial extra effort and is annoying and a waste of time and effort. BUT once I have lodged an answer I can update it regardless of the state of its kneecaps. So ... . || Aussitot - in some cases posting useful content before I have said my bit fully can lead to interaction with questioner and others and lead to a better answer. | OK?

Comment: @user36129 Note that now about 30 minutes after the question was posted there is already one close vote registered.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'll tell my friend he doesn't have to worry as much as he does :)

Comment: @user36129 5 hours / 3 closes - the force is strong with this one.